# How sites like StackOverflow prevent linking up account base on unverified email address in decentralized fashion?

Tags: openid

The OpenID protocol's email address is not verified.

Consider the case below:

1. I create a SO account using Gmail account, my email is abc@gmail.com
2. Now, another guy have way to fake at some OpenID provider which is also using abc@gmail.com, and he login into SO using this provider.
3. Now, SO will link up these two login methods, and the guy has full access to my SO account.

So, in practice, how to minimize the risk for the above hacks?

Comment: By using provider+email pair, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, you are making several assumptions:

- relaying party (SO in your example), does not verify provider and only identifies a user by  identifier (ie. email)
- relaying party trusts any provider to provide authentication (e.g. fake OpenID provider)

To minimize risk (this is by no means an exhaustive list, but it's a start)

- a user's OpenID should at least be (provider + email)
- this is counter intuitive to OpenID idea, but relay with only trusted providers instead of just anyone
- relay party should use nonce
- ssl between RP/OP

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case of Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange, accounts will only be merged if they have the same email address *and* the user logs in from a service that is known to verify email addresses. Services like Gmail, Facebook, and Yahoo verify your email address during sign-up, so it is safe to trust the email address that they return. If you use your own OpenID provider, then it won't be recognized, so the account would not automatically be merged.